# Axios promise resolving on pre-flight request response which makes associated GET execute out of order with rest of app

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, es6-promise, redux-thunk

Good day,

I am working on a React app that makes use of React-Redux (with Thunk) and Axios.

I have an action that I dispatch which makes an authenticated API call. Due to the fact that I have Authorization headers on a cross-origin request, there is a pre-flight request.

The problem that I have is that Axios seems to be running the .then() code once the pre-flight request returns rather than when the associated GET request returns. This results in the Reducer function updating state before the results of the API GET request return.

I have added some console.logs to give more details to illustrate the problem. As you can see the pre-flight request is sent in the first entry. The .then executes one the pre-flight request returns with 200. The action then fires off and the reducer updates the state. My app responds by re-rendering the container that was connected to Redux. The child components also then update. Then the GET request completes and returns with a 200. And at this point nothing further happens because the reducer was already updated in the  prior .then() mentioned above.

The action code is shown below. I have not pasted all the other code in as there are a number of files and they are relatively big. If needed I can include those too.
[image: Network tab details]

```
export const updatePlotDataInit = (datasetName, tableName, xFieldName, 
    yFieldName, chartId, chartType, plotId, newDomainStartDbIndex, newDomainEndDbIndex) => {
        console.log('[actions/plot.js.js] - [updatePlotDataInit] - [start of function]');
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(updatePlotDataStart());
        console.log('[actions/plot.js.js] - [updatePlotDataInit] - [just before api request]');
        instance.get( // custom axios instance with extra auth header used here
            `/v1/datasets/${datasetName}/tables/${tableName}/fields/data?xField=${xFieldName}&yField=${yFieldName}&chartType=${chartType}&domainStart=${newDomainStartDbIndex}&domainEnd=${newDomainEndDbIndex}`
            )
            .then(response => {
                console.log('[actions/plot.js.js] - [updatePlotDataInit] - [in .then before updatePlotDataSuccess]');
                // dispatch redux action for success case
                const currentLevel = response.data.metaData.current_level 
                const data = response.data.queryData.data //schema is available too
                //datasetId, tableId, xFieldId, xField, yFieldId, yField, chartId, plotIdVal, currentLevel, data
                dispatch( updatePlotDataSuccess( plotId, currentLevel, data ) );
                // console.log(response);
                console.log('[actions/plot.js.js] - [updatePlotDataInit] - [in .then after updatePlotDataSuccess]')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);

            // dispatch redux action for failure case
            dispatch(updatePlotDataFail(error));
            })
    }
};
```

I am not entirely sure but it seems that Axios is seeing the successful pre-flight response as suitable to resolve the promsie and hence the .then gets executed.

Does this seem to be the case? And if so how would I force Axios to wait for the GET/POST/PUT/etc to succeed before resolving the promise?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, I think. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I'm also having this issue with a patch request. Promise resolves on preflight response, but server is still processing the main request. How to await result of the actual request?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is for long time ago, but I think it could be useful for others who find this issue similar to their problem, with no answer...

for me it was just because of a careless coding :D,
here is my response inceptor, I missed "return" before Promise.resolve(axios(originalRequest));
I solved it by adding return :

```
AxiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        let refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
        if (
            refreshToken &&
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            !originalRequest._retry
        ) {
            originalRequest._retry = true;
            return axios
                .post(apiUrl + `auth/refreshtoken`, { refreshToken: refreshToken })
                .then((res) => {            
                    if (res.status === 200) {
                        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", res.data.accessToken);
                        console.log("Access token refreshed!" + res.data.accessToken);       
                        originalRequest.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + res.data.accessToken;
         //*************** I just return promise.resolve *****************//
                        return Promise.resolve(axios(originalRequest)); 
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });

        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
```